# How can I train Keras to make output layer identical to input layer?

Tags: machine-learning, keras

After 10000 epics, I can't seem to make a NN output a layer of 8 bits that is the same as its input.
I can get it to output a layer with one bit saying whether the input is even or odd.
But I can't even get it to output a layer with two bits, also saying whether the input is even or odd.

If I set try_this to 'even/odd', it becomes perfect after about 10 epochs. If I set try_this to 'even/odd/duplicated' -- which seems like the same thing! -- still won't train well.

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras

features = []
labels = []
# set features to every combination of 8 bits
for i in range(0,256) :
    b = bin(256+i)
    b = [ bit for bit in b ]
    b = b[-8:]
    features.append(b) # input: 8 bits

    try_this = 'output-mirrors-input'

    if try_this == 'output-mirrors-input' :
        """
            the following is my goal: output exactly what is input,
            but after 10000 epics, gets only about 30% accuracy
        """
        labels.append(b)
    elif try_this == 'even/odd' :
        """
            even or odd label
            this becomes perfect after only about 10 epics,
            but it isn't what i want
        """
        labels.append( [1] if i%2 else [0] )
    elif try_this == 'even/odd/duplicated' :
        """
            even or odd again,
            but after 10000 epochs, is only about 50% accurate!
        """
        labels.append( [1,1] if i%2 else [0,0] )

features = np.array(features,'float32')
labels = np.array(labels,'float32')

feature_len = len( features[0] )
label_len = len( labels[0] )

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Input( shape=[feature_len] )) # input layer
model.add(keras.layers.Dense( feature_len*2, activation='relu' )) # hidden layer
model.add(keras.layers.Dense( label_len )) # output layer

model.compile(
    loss = 'mean_squared_error',
    optimizer = 'adam',
    metrics = ['accuracy'],
)

model.fit( features,labels, epochs=10000, verbose=2 )
```

Comment: I was using relu because it seems better suited to 0 or 1 output, but tried sigmoid anyway, and it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: You trying to implement Autoencoder like network?

Comment: Trying to model a state transition. A system, for example is in state #1, it gets some input, and it is now in state #8. All of this can be represented with one-hot encoding. What I was trying to do here, is: system is in state #1, it gets no input, so it is now in state #1.

Comment: "Output the same thing as your input" seems like a VERY simple problem to me. Surely a NN can "solve" that!? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: the code above actually DOES work! The trouble was, I was using loss and accuracy to judge whether the model was making accurate predictions. When I added this prediction:

```
    prediction = np.around( model.predict( features ) ).tolist()
    correct = np.around(labels).tolist()
    if prediction == correct :
        print("success!")
    else :
        print("fail")
```

I could see it was making completely accurate predictions, and I was able to reduce the number of epochs to apx 100 with still perfect predictions!

So, apparently I need a better understanding of the accuracy and loss algorithms.